# Geometry Nodes: Chainsaw teeth or Tank Track or making instances to follow curve in motion

Tags: geometry-nodes

Didn't find a extremely simple nodesetup for this problem, especially concerning chainsaw's teeth or tank track. So, I ask:

How to make Chainsaw teeth or tank track or making instances to follow curve in motion with geometry nodes?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With the help of **[this](https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/sliding-instances-along-a-curve-in-blender-using-geometry-nodes/)** I shall summon this info here:

[image]

The input geometry is a looping curve object.

[image]